# NativeAdAdvanced - Incorrect native ad response. Click actions were not properly specified

Tags: android, admob, native-ads

I'm trying to implement NativeAd in my app.
Everything worked fine until yesterday, it's now printing these error logs.

```
I/Ads: WebView loading for native ads.
I/Ads: Javascript has loaded for native ads.
I/Ads: Received log message: <Google:HTML> Incorrect native ad response. Click actions were not properly specified

onAdFailedToLoad errorCode = 0
```

So I can't show native ads anymore.
Here's how I do the requests.

```
private AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();

private NativeAdOptions nativeAdOptions = new NativeAdOptions.Builder()
        .setAdChoicesPlacement(ADCHOICES_TOP_RIGHT)
        .setRequestMultipleImages(false)
        .setReturnUrlsForImageAssets(true)
        // Methods in the NativeAdOptions.Builder class can be
        // used here to specify individual options settings.
        .build();

AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(mContext, adUnitId)
            .forAppInstallAd(new NativeAppInstallAd.OnAppInstallAdLoadedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAppInstallAdLoaded(NativeAppInstallAd appInstallAd) {
                    refreshAd(appInstallAd);
                }
            })
            .forContentAd(new NativeContentAd.OnContentAdLoadedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onContentAdLoaded(NativeContentAd contentAd) {
                    refreshAd(contentAd);
                }
            })
            .withAdListener(adListener)
            .withNativeAdOptions(nativeAdOptions)
            .build();

adLoader.loadAd(adRequest);
```

If I comment out `forAppInstallAd` then the ads can be downloaded again. But the fill rate is very low.

Comment: Just like @RedBrogdon said. It's a bug from admob sdk. The problem disappeared after I changed to use real devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the SDK is rejecting the response sent down from the AdMob server, which is really weird. I don't think this is an issue that can be solved on StackOverflow, so I'd recommend creating a post in [AdMob's SDK support forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-admob-ads-sdk), where the support team can try to dig into the issue.