# How can I avoid getting error code 0 on Google Custom Template request?

Tags: android, double-click

I use `NativeCustomTemplateAd` in my Android app to display some banners in my app's Home page screen. Lately I got some reports that on some occasions these banners are not displayed, so I've triggered an analytics event every time this happens. Turns out that it happens for more than 10% of my daily active users.

After a lot of research and a long discussion with someone from Google support, I've found out that:

- it happens on any Android version but more than 80% on Android 8.0.0
- if I restart the device that has this issue it will work again for a random period of time
- it's not a problem with my code (I've tried CustomRenderingExample from Google samples project)
- it's not from our DFP setup (again, I've tried with the sample DFP AD Unit ID)
- I've done some Charles debugging and I see that the following request
  `https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/production/native_ads.html` returns an HTML 200 response which contains, among others, the following message:

  "Incorrect native ad response. Click actions were not properly specified",ha="Missing required native ads fields."

With me having tried pretty much everything to solve this issue, unsuccessfully, and with Google's support close to zero, this is my last take: has anyone encountered something similar when using NativeCustomTemplateAds? Is there *anything* that I can do to have it working on all of my daily active users?

Thank you!

Comment: Whether you are using kotlin or java?

Comment: I'm using Kotlin, as the Google samples projects. What difference does it make?

Comment: Can you give me a sample code?

Comment: Maybe you can try admob native ads for android

Comment: Found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49065562/nativeadadvanced-incorrect-native-ad-response-click-actions-were-not-properly). Please post in AdMob's SDK support forum, where the support team can try to dig into the issue. Check this forum: [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-admob-ads-sdk/Missing$20required$20native$20ads$20fields%7Csort:date](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-admob-ads-sdk/Missing$20required$20native$20ads$20fields%7Csort:date)

Comment: I think problem might be in `",ha="` parameter? are there any cases when that parameter is not being set for user in app?  maybe you can check at first (before making a request to the url) if that parameter is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of chat with the Google Support, it turns out there actually was an issue on their side. They fixed it and the issue should not reproduce as before.

The answer that got the reward is basically just a copy-paste of other posting this issue which technically should've been a comment, not an answer.

Anyway, I hope that others who might have encountered this issue can find a solution in my answer. Also upgrading to the latest version of the Google Play Ads SDK (17.1.1 at the moment) was recommended by the member of the Google Support.